# Program that counts txt files in folder and its subfolders throws NullPointerException

Tags: java

I don't have much expirience in Java programming, and I tried to write simple program that iterates through some directory and its subfolders and counts txt files. I have used this code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Fajlovi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

        Fajlovi n=new Fajlovi();
        File f=new File("D:\\");

        System.out.println("Number of txt files is"+n.listaj(f));

    }

    public int listaj(File f){
        int count=0;
        File[] s= f.listFiles();

        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){

            if(s[i].isDirectory())
                count+=listaj(s[i]);
            else if(s[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                count++;

            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Problem is that it works sometimes depending which directory I specify, but often it throws `NullPointerException` and stops execution. I have used some commands to follow execution steps, and I found out that it stops when `count+=listaj(s[i])` is called for some directory that I even can't find on my computer and its not hidden.

Comment: You should add the stack trace and the name of the folder that is causing the exception. Also add which OS you are running this on.

Comment: If you can run through a debugger that would help. Alternatively, every time you create and use an object, output the object's `toString()` and check for nulls to determine if the error is being thrown by your code or because of [probably invalid] input to a system library.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau seems like Windows "File f=new File("D:\\");"

Comment: Assuming one of the below answers isn't the answer, I don't have time to debug this myself, check here for the Java7 NIO tutorial which may help.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: Any time you are trying to get help understanding an exception, please include the full message and stack trace you're seeing.  Without that, it's very hard for other people to debug your problem accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws NullPointerException when your program is trying to access those secure directories which comes under the System Files and folder.
In your code when `s[i].isDirectory()` becomes `true` then it starts exploring `s[i]` directory and as the JVM doesn't have access to that secure location it returns null value.
You can check whether the directory is null or not and then only try to find `.txt` file in that directory.
Hope this explanation answer your question.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the explanation. Point wasnt to find code that can do this operation. I just wanted to know why my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`File.listFiles()` will return null if it is invoked on a file that is not a directory.  If that happens, your loop condition will cause the `NullPointerException`.  This makes sense if it is being invoked, as you mention at the end, on something that does not exist.

Why this is happening requires more information.  What is the "file that [you] can't even find on [your] computer?"

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes when there is an invalid directory/file used.

From the documentation about **listFiles()**:

> Returns {@code null} if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

This code should prevent future NullPointerExceptions:

```
File[] s = f.listFiles();
if (s != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        if (s[i].isDirectory())
            count += listaj(s[i]);
        else if (s[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            count++;

        }
    }
    return count;
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid directory");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works excellent now :) Thank you all and excuse me for not being precise enough in my qustion. It's my first post here, it will be better next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me (running on Win 7):

```
import java.io.*;

public class txtCount
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     txtCount n=new txtCount();
     File f=new File("D:\\");

     System.out.println("Number of txt files is " + n.listAndCount(f));
  }

   public int listAndCount(File f)
   {
       int count=0;
       for (final File fileEntry : f.listFiles()) 
       {
          if (fileEntry.isDirectory())
          {
             count += listAndCount(fileEntry);
          }
          else if(fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
          {
              count++;
          }
       }
       return count;
    }
}
```